# Как сделать вложенное меню в расширении Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Вот такой код создает только верхний пункт в меню, а вложенные не создает. Как я только не извращался. И другие расширения ковырял, смотрел как там. Вот то же самое пишу - не работает. Я уже не знаю как быть.

```js
function pasteRandom(info, tab) {
 alert("item " + info.menuItemId + " was clicked");
 alert("info: " + JSON.stringify(info));
 alert("tab: " + JSON.stringify(tab));
}

function createMenu() {

 var urls = [
        "*://*/*"
    ];
 
 var root = chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Вставить данные из RandomUser", 
  id: "c_main",
  contexts: ["editable"]
 });

 chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Имя", 
  parentId: c_main, 
  id: "c_name",
  onclick: pasteRandom,
        documentUrlPatterns: urls
 });

 chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Email", 
  parentId: root, 
  id: "c_email",
  onclick: pasteRandom,
        documentUrlPatterns: urls
 });

}

createMenu();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Рабочие примеры](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contextmenus)

Нас в них вот что интересует:

```
var parent = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Test parent item"});
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
   "title": "Child 1",
   "parentId": parent,
   "onclick": genericOnClick
});
var child2 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
   "title": "Child 2", 
   "parentId": parent,
   "onclick": genericOnClick
});
console.log("parent:" + parent + " child1:" + child1 + " child2:" + child2);
```

В чем разница? В примере в свойство `parentId` передается ссылка на объект, контекстного меню ( `parent` ), у вас же это какое-то кастомное свойство `id`
Попробуйте так

```
var root = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Вставить данные из RandomUser", 
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Имя", 
    parentId: root, 
});

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Email", 
    parentId: root, 
});
```

для начала, а потом уже добавляйте обработчики событий и так далее.

Comment: вот код нынешний. Если в дочерние пункты не добавлять обработчик onclick, то они выводятся. А если раскомментировать строку нижнюю, то обработчик и к родительскому пункту цепляется, а это не нужно. http://pastebin.com/9wxdJxsw

Comment: Ю-ху-хууууу!!! Заработало!!!! Вот код: http://pastebin.com/n0hRsRKD. А кто подскажет как получить идентификатор элемента, на котором был щелчек по пункту меню? Например внутри textarea был щелкнут дочерний элемент Email. Как мне вставить Email именно в этот текстареа?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> parentId: c_main,
> ```

Вероятно, этот код падает из-за использования необъявленной переменной. Попробуй так:

```
parentId: "c_main",
```

или так:

```
parentId: root
```

---

Кстати, думаю, `alert` такой всё равно не заработает. Замени его на `window.open` (не забыв прибавить `data:text/plain,`) или `console.log` для проверки. Только во втором случае не забудь открыть консоль расширения (которую ты видимо ещё не нашёл), а не страницы.